# how to acces to property inside json using angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I just trying to access a key in my json but I can't, I don't understand my mistake. because otherwise I have an [object object].

I also know that with my current code if I use the keyvalue pipe it would work without me accessing the color key.

the error I have is: **Property 'color' does not exist on type 'Itoto []'**

**json**

```
{
  "color": [ // I want to access to color
   [
    "1", 
    "red",
    "green"
   ]
  ]
}
```

**ts.file**

```
get() {
 this.service.get().subscribe((data: Itoto[])=> {
  this.array = data.color //i try this but i have property color does not exist on type 'Itoto[]'
 });
```

**interface**

```
export interface Itoto {
 color:[
 id:number
 ]
}
```

Comment: You're receiving an array, so you need to map. `data.map(item => console.log(item.color));`

Comment: color does not exist on type Itoto ARRAY. color is in data[0].color.

Comment: it seems you signed the type wrong here `data: Itoto[]`. it probably should be `data: Itoto`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to determine if you need to receive an array of `Itoto[]`, or only one `Itoto`.

So I think you have both solutions :

1rst solution : Map to your received datas.

```js
this.service.get().subscribe((data: Itoto[])=> {
  this.array = data.map(item => item.color);
});
```

2nd solution : Return a single `Itoto`

```js
this.service.get().subscribe((data: Itoto)=> {
  this.array = data.color;
});
```

---

**EDIT 1**

I reproduce your code on Stackblitz and many things seems to be wrong.
Actually, according to the JSON and the `get()` method, you want to work with a single `Itoto`. You will have to map over the `color` property.

So here is the ts :

```js
export interface Itoto {
  color: string[][];
}

array: Itoto;

res: Itoto = {
  "color": 
   [[
    "1", 
    "red",
    "green"
  ]]
};

constructor() {
  this.get().subscribe((data: Itoto) => {
    this.array = data;
  });
}

get(): Observable<Itoto> {
  return of(this.res);
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let color of array.color">
  <p>The array : {{ color | json }}</p>
  Single values :  <span *ngFor="let item of color">{{ item | json }}</span>
</div>
```

Here is a working Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-11c8h4?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: for the 2nd solution i have this error: `type '[id:number]'  is not assignable to type 'Itoto[] type number is not assignable to type 'Itoto`

Comment: @Jean What is the type of `this.data` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only color property in your json then you will directly get color in your response. you need to change type of response  Itoto[] to Itoto.

**.ts file**

```
get() {
 this.service.get().subscribe((data: Itoto)=> {
  this.array = data.color; //color as data
 });
```

I console data from response and you can see the result.

[image]